# Play multiple animations at once

Tags: unity-game-engine

Say I'm making a tool for another developer to animate text. I have a fade animation, which fades the text, and I have a move animation, that moves the text off the screen. Now, I can do anim.Play("Fade"); and it works fine. Same with anim.Play("Move");. But If I wan't the text to move AND fade, simply calling anim.Play("Fade"); and anim.Play("Move"); at the same time won't work. Is there a way I can call both a once? I don't see why this wouldn't be possible because they both modify different components. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with legacy animation system, you can use this method 
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Blend.html

If you are working with mecanim, you should use animation layers http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html